# Ошибка указания дирректории при выполнении функции

Tags: php

У меня есть функция, которая пропорционально сжимает фотографию:

```
/* 
$w_o и h_o - ширина и высота выходного изображения 
*/ 
function resize($newName, $w_o = false, $h_o = false) { 
  if (($w_o < 0) || ($h_o < 0)) { 
    echo "Некорректные входные параметры"; 
    return false; 
  } 
  $types = array('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg'); // Массив с типами изображений
  $directory = '../img/avatars/';
  $directory_to_file = $directory . $newName;
  list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($directory_to_file); // Получаем размеры и тип изображения (число) 
  $ext = $types[$type]; // Зная "числовой" тип изображения, узнаём название типа 
  if ($ext) { 
    $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext; // Получаем название функции, соответствующую типу, для создания изображения 
    $img_i = $func($newName); // Создаём дескриптор для работы с исходным     изображением 
  } else { 
    echo 'Некорректное изображение'; // Выводим ошибку, если формат изображения     недопустимый 
    return false; 
  } 
  /* Если указать только 1 параметр, то второй подстроится пропорционально */ 
  if (!$h_o) $h_o = $w_o / ($w_i / $h_i); 
  if (!$w_o) $w_o = $h_o / ($h_i / $w_i); 
  $img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o); // Создаём дескриптор для выходного изображения 
  imagecopyresampled($img_o, $img_i, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_o, $h_o, $w_i, $h_i); // Переносим изображение из исходного в выходное, масштабируя его 
  $func = 'image'.$ext; // Получаем функция для сохранения результата 
  return $func($img_o, $newName); // Сохраняем изображение в тот же файл, что и     исходное, возвращая результат этой операции 
  } 
  /* Вызываем функцию с целью уменьшить изображение до ширины в 66 пикселей, а         высоту уменьшив пропорционально, чтобы не искажать изображение */ 
  resize($newName, 66); // Вызываем функцию 
  if ( !resize($newName, 66) ) { 
    echo "Функция не выполнена!"; 
  } else { 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile); 
    echo "Фотография была загружена!"; 
  }
```

Но при её выполнении выдает ошибку:

> **Warning** : getimagesize(../img/avatars/6.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **W:\domains\mysite\settings.php** on line **113** Некорректное изображение

Чего он не видит? Пути и т.п. вроде указаны правильно..

Comment: 6.png где лежит, рядом с файлом функции? Для надежности надо задавать полный путь к файлу.

Comment: а где ты укзал пути? чета я не могу найти эту строку

Comment: если вы передаете просто `6.png` то он ищет ее в той же директории где и исполняемый файл. Поскольку у вас картинка в другой директории, то вполне логично, что появляется такая ошибка. Вы говорите, что пути указаны, но они тут нигде не указаны.

Comment: @teran Я поправил, 9 10 11 строчки изменены ( добавил $directory = ... ), но он все равно не видит пути, который указан в Warning (тоже поправил), хотя такой путь есть

Comment: Я указал путь, посмотрите поправленный вопрос, но он все равно не видит пути, хотя он такой и есть

Comment: @fedornabilkin я поправил код, но он все равно не видит пути, хотя такой имеется (см комментарий выше какие строчки я отрдактировал)

Comment: Покажи полный путь к исполняющему файлу и полный путь к картинке. Думаю сразу разберешься, где проблема.

Comment: попробуйте добавить `__DIR__` перед именем файла

Comment: я так понимаю, что .`..` будет указывать на `domains/img` ? почему вы пишите `..`? вам ведь наверняка надо `domains/mystie/img` ?